# Scheduling execution of 2 functions

Tags: c, timer, pthreads, glib

I was already told to use glib but I'm not allowed to upgrade glib.
So I can't use this code:

```
GMainLoop* loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
g_timeout_add_seconds (5, mainLoop, &data);
g_timeout_add_seconds (15*60, editTree, &data);
g_main_loop_run (loop);
```

Is there any alternative how can I call 2 functions basing on timers?
The first function should be called every 5 sec. The second should be called every 15´ and at best just after the first is ready. I have glib tree there which should be accessed (read only by the first function) and modified by the second one.
Do I need threads here? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[g_timeout_add_seconds](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) was added in glib-2.14, but [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) and [g_timeout_add_full](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-full) have been around since at least 2.0.  They take milliseconds instead of seconds, so just multiply by 1000 and you should be fine.